# How to add a dialog to the default dialogs

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I am having a dialog that is in a behavior. I am setting this behavior to be default and this is the way my dialog to be available on start.

I found that the default topics that are from the basic channel (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/nao/basic_channel_conversation.html) are all initialized by 'run_dialog_dev/.' (I guess this is from the basic channel too or it is a part of the factory state of the robot).

So is there a way to put this dialog(topic) to be as the part of the default ones without putting it in a behavior, just by adding the topic to the robot. And this topic to be auto included in 'run_dialog_dev/.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your dialog topic initialized by 'run_dialog_dev/.' alongside with the Basic Channel you should declare it as a 'collaborative dialog' (see [Choregraphe documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/software/choregraphe/objects/dialog_topic.html?highlight=collaborative)).

[image: Add new dialog topic window]

When creating your topic, make sure to tick the checkbox at the bottom of the window.

Your Choregraphe project won't have to contain a behavior, you can just have it contain your dialog.